# Distinct select with where filter on ClickHouse distributed table failed

Tags: database, clickhouse

I met a problem when I am testing a query on a distributed table.

The SQL is like this:

```
select distinct OriginCityName from on_time.ontime_all t where t."OriginStateName" = 'California'
```

'on_time.ontime_all' is a distributed table with column OriginCityName, OriginStateName and some others. And the error:

```
Received exception from server (version 1.1.54381):
Code: 171. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000, ::1. DB::Exception: Block structure mismatch in UNION stream: different number of columns:
OriginCityName String String(size = 0)
OriginCityName String String(size = 0), OriginStateName String String(size = 0). 

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.186 sec.
```

However, if I do one of the following to the SQL, the error dissapears:

- remove distinct
- remove the where clause
- replace where with prewhere
- add the "OriginStateName" column in the where clause to the select part as well
- change select part to `select distinct *`

This kind of SQL is important to my application, so could anybody help me solve this? Is it a bug or is it a limitation of ClickHouse? Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the error go away if you don't use the table aliasing ?

Comment: @George No. The error persists.

Comment: Then, I would suggest creating a simulated environement and dataset to reproduce the problem (just launch two machine with vagrant to do this, it's not overly complicate). See if you can reproduce the problem there (if not, see what the difference between the two is), if you can reproduce the problem, post it on github as an issue in clickhouse repo with steps to do so (or post all the details you can now, and, if you are asked for how to replicate, then setup the environment and give the instructions). It may be a fault of how distributed queries are handled when you have Distinct

Comment: But personally, I don't remember having issues with DISTINCT/GROUP BY/WHERE in distributed queries, maybe it has to do with your table definition or something obvious in your query I'm not seeing..., out of curiosity, what engines do you tables use ? Personally I only used the standard MergeTree a lot, some of the MergeTree variation might have restrictions in distributed queries

Comment: @George Thank you.  The engine I used is MergeTree. The problem was produced with the OnTime test data on the ClickHouse documentation. I changed it to cluster version (2 nodes) by executing create table ... on cluster ... () engine=MergeTree ... and create table ... () engine=Distributed... and I can easily reproduce it by only execute the 2 create tables and the select statement. However, if I manually create very simple test MergeTree and Distributed tables, there are no problems.

Comment: I posted the issue on the Github several days ago, and now I've added a comment on how to reproduce it. Hope someone will notice that.

Comment: Hmh... if you have time send your table definitions, since the dataset is public I can try to replicate it. Also, when you execute the query, are there any error logs from clickhouse or zookeeper ? (You can tail the error log while doing the query via `journlactl -f | grep -i clickhouse` and `journalctl -f | grep -i zookeeper` respectively)

Comment: journalctl -f shows no text containing clickhouse or zookeeper. You can simply create 2 tables, and doesn't need to import any data, execute the select and the issue will be shown up.  Since there are so many columns in the table definition, which is too many to be included in the comment, you can see it in the comment of the issue I posted on GitHub here: https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/issues/2373 (issue link)

Comment: @George Did you replicate the issue with the info I provided? Or did I do something wrong? I'm trying to utilize ClickHouse in our own data analysis product. We are not familiar with C/C++, and we are not able to do anything with ClickHouse itself, so any help from you would be so grateful!